# What passage from The Once and Future King does Professor X read?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, t-h-white, marvel

In *X-Men: Apocalypse*, Professor X reads a passage from T.H. White's *The Once and Future King* to his students. Which passage did he read?

<sub>Answer preferably should contain the quote.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Xavier quotes a few lines:**

> XAVIER:  ... to break forth bloodily, then the past must be obliterated and a
> new start made.
> [...]
> XAVIER: Let us now start fresh without remembrance, rather than live forward
> and backward at the same time.

The original passage:

> The blessing of forgetfulness: that was the first essential. If
> everything one did, or which one's fathers had done, was an endless
> sequence of Doings doomed **to break forth bloodily, then the past must
> be obliterated and a new start made.** Man must be ready to say: Yes,
> since Cain there has been injustice, but we can only set the misery
> right if we accept a status quo. Lands have been robbed, men slain,
> nations humiliated. **Let us now start fresh without remembrance, rather
> than live forward and backward at the same time.** We cannot build the
> future by avenging the past. Let us sit down as brothers, and accept
> the Peace of God.
>
> —*The Once and Future King*

Comment: Do you have a source for the first quote, or did you transcribe it from the actual film?

Comment: @ibid - http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=x-men-apocalypse

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](http://www.mystatesman.com/news/entertainment/movies/x-men-apocalypse-stumbles-under-its-own-weight/nrS3P/) he quotes the line "Let us now start fresh without remembrance" which dealt with avoiding the desire for revenge. I haven't seen the film so I'm not sure if he quoted more of the lines before or after, but more of the original T.H. White quote can be read [here](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/918297-man-must-be-ready-to-say-yes-since-cain-there). Google books shows the quote can be found on page 631 of [this edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=kdLT8_tnpmEC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22let%20us%20now%20start%20fresh%22), which is 639 pages long, so apparently it's from very near the end.

Comment: It sounded like he quoted more than just one line.